# Error 403 when pushing to GitHub repository: Need to change Git username associated with repository

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am facing an issue while trying to push changes to my GitHub repository. The error message I'm encountering is as follows:

```
remote: Permission to mehdiergaibi/stock-managment.git denied to Mehdi-Ergaibi.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mehdiergaibi/stock-managment.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Upon investigation, I realized that the username associated with the repository is set to my older account (Mehdi-Ergaibi), which I'm not actively using. In my Git configuration, the correct username for my new GitHub account is set to mehdiergaibi.

How can I change the Git username associated with this repository to ensure that it uses the correct username (mehdiergaibi) instead of the old one (Mehdi-Ergaibi)? Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to the old account, you can transfer the ownership of the GitHub repository to the new account in the repository settings. In this way, you can keep not only the codes and commit history but also other things like issues and pull requests. After the transfer, you can use `git remote set-url origin <new url>` to change the local config.

Otherwise, you can create a new empty repository at https://github.com/new, use `git remote set-url origin <new url>` to change the local config, and then use `git push -u origin <master or main>` to push current codes to the new GitHub repository.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the repository is existing on my new github account, i dont know even how the username associated with the repository is set to my older account witch i had 3 years ago.
i tried ``` git remote set-url origin <new url> ``` but same error

Comment: @mehdiergaibi Maybe I misread your question. Is it your GitHub credential, not the remote repository URL, that is wrong?

Comment: yes i think it's about credentials, but the problem is git is trying to push to another account as Mehdi-Ergaibi ( wrong one ), but the repository is existing on another account and git configs's username is mehdiergaibi ( correct one )